# Salesforce Summer 18 broke sweet alert 2

Tags: salesforce, sweetalert2, salesforce-lightning

I have a problem that might interest some. I was using sweet alert 2 in my lightning component bundle "pages". It was working like a charm:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFSvN.jpg

But now, in my sandbox after the summer 18 update the sweet alert modal turned into a bitter corner alert:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPa8h.jpg

Can anyone please help me? 
I uploaded the js file from the sweet alert website as a static resource in SalesForce.

I am not sure if the css from sweet alert is being modified by the theme or if it is something else, but I don't know how to fix it, and I have to until this update is applied to production orgs. I also accept suggestions of modals, but I did not find anything as easy and nice looking as this.

Comment: make sure you're using `sweetalert2.all.min.js` which contains both JS and styles.

Comment: I did not try this solution exactly, but I solved it! I downloaded only the css, uploaded as sweetAlertStyle and used the tag: `<ltng:require styles="{!$Resource.sweetAlertStyle}" scripts="{!$Resource.sweetAlert}"/>`

Answer (score 0):

So, I solved it. The solution is similar to what Limon proposed. I downloaded only the css, uploaded as sweetAlertStyle (static resource) and used the tag:

`<ltng:require styles="{!$Resource.sweetAlertStyle}" scripts="{!$Resource.sweetAlert}"/>`

The sweetAlert was the script I downloaded from sweetAlert2 website (also uploaded as a static resource).

PS: I had to change the script a little bit to get it working even before I had this problem, something about the function that checks if an object has some property, but this is another problem...